# Box design tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, tikz-styles, boxes, box

I found this box, but didn't know the design. Can you tell me which library or packages are used to design it. Thanks[image]

Comment: This can be achieved using the `tcolorbox` package, for example.

Comment: Probably though it has not been made with latex but with an application such as InDesign or Illustrator. It's not so common to create such boxes with tcolorbox, and if it's possible it needs some extra work to achieve. If is on a pdf somebody can see with which application was created.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tikzset{framed/.style={path picture={
\fill[blue!50!violet!50, even odd rule, rounded corners]
(path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east) 
([shift={( 2pt, 4pt)}] path picture bounding box.south west) -- 
([shift={( 2pt,-2pt)}] path picture bounding box.north west) -- 
([shift={(-2pt,-4pt)}] path picture bounding box.north east) -- 
([shift={(-6pt, 6pt)}] path picture bounding box.south east) -- cycle;
}}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[framed, text width=10cm, inner sep=15pt] {\lipsum[][1-10]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Text box with a purple frame]

Edit: With label

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tikzset{exercise/.style={path picture={
\fill[blue!50!violet!50, even odd rule, rounded corners]
(path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east) 
([shift={( 2pt, 4pt)}] path picture bounding box.south west) -- 
([shift={( 2pt,-2pt)}] path picture bounding box.north west) -- 
([shift={(-2pt,-4pt)}] path picture bounding box.north east) -- 
([shift={(-6pt, 6pt)}] path picture bounding box.south east) -- cycle;
},
label={[anchor=west, xshift=1em, yshift=-1pt, rotate=6, fill=blue!50!violet!50]north west:Exercise #1:},
}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[exercise=1, text width=10cm, inner sep=15pt] {\lipsum[][1-10]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Framed text with an "Exercise 1:" label]

Comment: thank you very much, how can I add exercise like in the picture above

Comment: tnakn you very much

Comment: No need to write thank you - just accept the answer, if it answers your question.